# SSJS Split String

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, split

How to use split function in SSJS to split String? 
In my case, I have given the String and , the way I want to split is as follows :
My String : I want 2 splits
dfc_1 : dfc_ and 1
dfc_45932 : dfc_ and 45932

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
var parts = source.split(/(?<=_)/);
```

Where `/.../` is a regular expression, `(?<=...)` is a look-behind, and `_` is the thing you're trying to split after.

Comment: Thanks it worked this way : split1 = source.split("_");

Comment: Split and many other javascript string manipulation functions can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split